# Looking for someone who can speak german and can verify if the author did a mistake

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently reading a textbook for analysis 2, and I stumbled over a definition which does not fit with the explanation:

Shouldnt the marked part be $V \subseteq U$? All definitions that I found online also would state the definition with $V \subseteq U$

[image]

Comment: If those are the axioms of a neighbourhood basis at a point, then yes, it is the wrong way round.

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: Yes exactly thats what it describes :) I am really happy if this gets clearified, cause I co couldnt wrap my head around this wrong definition

Comment: Is that from Amann-Escher?

Comment: Otto Forster: Analysis 2

Comment: It was already found by others: http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~forster/books/an2/an2err11.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you are right. Otherwise just $\mathfrak D=\{X\}$ would always be neighbourhood basis.

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I thought, especially, his describtion was the correct one, so I got completly confused

Comment: @CoffeeArabica I think we should tell the author .

Comment: Yes of course, shall I?

Comment: @CoffeeArabica Go ahead if you want to do it. His mail seems to be forster@math.lmu.de . Also it would be cool if you put me (mail@maximilianjanisch.com) in the CC .

Comment: @CoffeeArabica Nevermind, he already knows about it as shown by MaoWao

Comment: Ahh I see :) never mind then

Comment: @CoffeeArabica Maybe he‘ll give a nice reply anyway :)